# Changing the color of a select tag after clicking on a option with class placeholder

Tags: jquery, html, css

My code looks like the following

```js
$(document).ready(function{
 
 $('.#situation').on("click", function{
  console.log('clicked');
  
 });
 
 
});
```

```css
.placeholder_color{
 color: #828282;
}
```

```html
<select name="situation" id="situation">
  <option selected="selected">Current Situation</option>
  <option class="placeholder_color" value="Unemployed">Unemployed</option>
  <option class="placeholder_color" value="Employed">Employed</option>

</select>
```

At the moment, the select tag has a color as you can see, almost like a placeholder.
I want to be able to change the text color  when I click on the option tags that have the class placeholder.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make an `on change` event on the `select` not on the `option` . And then find the `selected` option and check if that selected option hasClass `placeholder` . If it does, addClass `live` to `select` . If not, then remove the class `live` from `select`

see snippet below

Let me know if it helps

```js
$('select').on("change", function() {
  var opt = $(this).find("option:selected")
  if ($(opt).hasClass("placeholder")) {
    $(this).addClass("live")
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("live")
  }
});
```

```css
#situation {
  color: #828282;
}
#situation option {
 color:#828282;
}
#situation.live {
  color: red;
}

select {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:    none;
   appearance:         none;
}
/* for IE */
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="situation" id="situation">
  <option selected="selected">Current Situation</option>
  <option class="placeholder" value="Unemployed">Unemployed</option>
  <option class="placeholder" value="Employed">Employed</option>
  <option selected="selected">Current Situation</option>
</select>
```

Comment: There is just something I noticed in the behaviour of your code: After clicking on Employed or unemplyed, all the option tags color go red. Ideally I do not want to change the color of the option tag. Just the select instead

Comment: I was about to paste the same thing.@Nadj options are under select.

Comment: @Nadj changed the answer. see now

Comment: @Nadj  you misspelled `function` at `document ready` . it should be `function() `

Comment: Yes I just noticed. Is there a way I can remove the arrow in all browsers. I only know about webkit-appearence which is not for all browsers.
I know it is not part of my question so am still voting on your answer and hope you can help if possible.

Comment: @Nadj edited the answer with solutions for webkit moz and ie. Also you should change your question back to the original one. So it doesn't cause confusion

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#situation').on("click", function(){
    $('.placeholder').toggleClass('live');
  });  
});
```

```css
#situation{
  color: #828282;
}

.live{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="situation" id="situation">
 <option class="placeholder" value="Unemployed"> Unemployed </option>
 <option class="placeholder" value="Employed"> Employed </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking options are a bit tricky. You can use a change trigger on the select box but then it could be a little difficult to figure out the placeholder class. So you can use the below to cover your needs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#situation').on('click', function(ev) {
    if (ev.offsetY < 0) {
      //user clicks on option
      $(this).toggleClass("live");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#situation, #situation option {
  color: #828282;
}

#situation.live {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="situation" id="situation">
 <option selected="selected">Current Situation</option>
 <option class="placeholder" value="Unemployed">Unemployed</option>
 <option class="placeholder" value="Employed">Employed</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this is changing the class also when click on the first option, or on a 4th option ( if he would have one ) . and `. You can use a change trigger on the select box but than it's a little difficult to figure out the placeholder class` . It's not difficult, just check the class of the selected option